# make element smaller instead of having it drop to new line

Tags: html, css

In this layout I am developing, at 1124px and less in width, the green part of the header drops to a new line.

How can I get it and its contents to decrease in width as the viewport decreases in width while maintaining everything, in the header, in one line?

Right now the ratio between the pink element and the green element is that the pink takes up 20% of the header and the green takes up the remaining 80% of the width.

The input inside the green should also resize smaller in width as the its parent, the green section, does.

Here is a link to where this is happening: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/270523/help/new.html

As requested, here is a JSFiddle replicating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/d7k43/

and the basic css:

```
#logo{
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
    min-width:225px;
    background:pink;
}
#input{
    height:100%;
    width:80%;
    background:green;    
}
```

Comment: Please place your code in a js fiddle, and in the body of this question.  What happens when that link breaks?  The question becomes useless to all future visitors, and no one else with the same problem is assisted.

Comment: @Daedalus
ah, okay. I understand. I will do that from now on

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do it _now?_

Comment: @Daedalus Well, by the answer I chose I think it is clear that it was a mathematical calculation error. And the answer covers how to fix it. The link isn't really necessary. But, I can see how it would be necessary in a more involved programming question where I would post the code and not a link.

Comment: Whether the answer solved your problem or not, what I said still applies to _right now_, as this question could still be useful to any who might look it up.. so, really, please fix it.

Comment: @Daedalus okay, my apologies. I will make a jsfiddle and edit the question with its link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `#logo { min-width: 225px }`. When 0.2X = 225px, X = 1125px total width.

Your green area will still take up 80% of the total width, but the pink area's width will not shrink smaller than 225px. So when the window is less than 1125px, the pink area will take up more than 20% of the total width, which causes the green area to be pushed to a new line.

Example: 500px width window: 225px + .8*(500px) = 625px > 500px.